# Update database fields hourly with Python/Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

Suppose I have 1000 user_ids in a table and I would run every hour to get from Google API info and update 3 fields in that table. How would the impact be and how can it be done efficiently?

**I've seen this variant:**

```
m = Module.objects.get(user_id=1).update(field_one=100, field_two=200, field_three=300)
```

**And this one:**

```
m = Module.objects.get(user_id=1)
m.field_one = 100
m.field_two = 200
m.field_three = 300
m.save()
```

Also how can it be done so that it will run every hour and grab that information? Never done something like this.

Comment: Why every hour? Your 1000 users won't be on your site 24 hours a day 365 days a year. Most sites have many users, but only a few regular users. The rest lost interest. So you might think of a rule that checks less often. Kickoff a task when a user logs in?

Answer (score 2):

Use Redis, Celery to setup asynchronous task queue every hour. Look here https://realpython.com/blog/python/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/ for more info on how to setup asych task queue system for django.

Here is the code for `tasks.py`

```
from celery.task import periodic_task
from celery.schedules import crontab  


@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute=0, hour='*/1'))
def get_data_from_google_api():
    data_from_google =ping_google_api() # ping google api to get data
    return Module.objects.get(user_id=1).update(field_one= data_from_google['field_one'], field_two= data_from_google['field_two'], field_three= data_from_google['field_three'])
```

Look here for more info :

1. https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/06/23/scheduling-tasks-celery/
2. [How to run a Django celery task every 6am and 6pm daily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32449845/how-to-run-a-django-celery-task-every-6am-and-6pm-daily)

Answer (score 1):

Fof this purpose you need to run background queries with periodic taks.
Here is most popular in django [task-queue-libs](https://github.com/rosarior/awesome-django#task-queue)
For example, if you decide use celery, you can write simple periodic task:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import periodic_task

@periodic_task(
name='UPDATE_USER',
run_every=crontab(
    minute='1',
    hour='1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22'))
def update_user():
    #get some value from api
    Module.objects.filter(user_id=1).update(
        field_one=value, field_two=value, field_three=value)
```

All settings for django you can look in [celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)