# Django-Celery Scheduling Daily Tasks on Windows Server

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I have to schedule a task to run every Monday through Saturday. I downloaded django-celery to accomplish the task. I followed the tutorial on the [Celery site](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) and I used and looked at a few stack overflow posts, for example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23563934/django-how-to-run-a-function-everyday) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32449845/how-to-run-a-django-celery-task-every-6am-and-6pm-daily)

I did a mix and match with the above posts and with this two great tutorials: [Rhatore](https://www.codementor.io/ankurrathore/asynchronous-task-with-rabbitmq-celery-and-django-8904ceway) and [Freitas](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/20/how-to-use-celery-with-django.html)

This is my folder structure:

```
Application
    | apps
         | app1
              | __init__.py
              | tasks.py
              | urls.py
              | views.py    
    | Application
         | __init__.py
         | celery.py
         | settings.py
         | urls.py
         | wsgi.py
```

**Settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_celery_beat',
    'apps.app1',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True    
USE_TZ = True

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://localhost'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
```

**__init__.py** In the **init** under the Application

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

from .celery import app as celery_app

    __all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Application.settings')

app = Celery('Application')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**tasks.py** - for simplicity sake I reduced the task to a simple print command

```
from celery import shared_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import periodic_task
from celeryapp.emails import send_feedback_email
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *

logger=get_task_logger(__name__)

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=21, minute=32, day_of_week=0-5))
def simple_print():
    print("Hello World!")
```

I ran:

```
celery -A Application -1 info
```

And then `python manage.py runserver`
 21:32 UTC passed and it did not print. I expected to see "Hello World" printed at 21:32 UTC in the terminal as per the task specified in tasks.py. It did not print.

I also ran:

```
celery -A Application worker -l info
celery -A Application beat -l info
python manage.py runserver
```

in different terminals. It did not execute the task.

Guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain your problem in more detail. Or maybe "it did not print" - is an explanation of problem? What did you expect?

Comment: Alex thank you for your question. I edited my question. Basically, what I'm trying to do is to print "Hello World" to the terminal using a cron.

Comment: If you substitute `print` with file-`write` or `logging.info` or maybe database insert - would you get "Hello World!"?

Comment: I tried     f = open("myfile.txt", "x") and it didn't create a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code was correct. The problem was due to the OS. I'm using Windows and Celery 4.0 does not support Windows. This question was very useful: [How to Run Celery on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255548/how-to-run-celery-on-windows). I installed gevent and it worlks now.

```
pip install gevent
celery -A Application beat -l info
celery -A Application worker -l info -P gevent
```

If you get another error along the lines of "Fatal error in launcher..." try:

```
python -m celery -A Application beat -l info
python -m celery -A Application worker -l info -P gevent
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have both the worker and the beat running, so that celery will know if it has to run a periodic task at a certain time.

Something like this should help you in your local environment.

```
celery -A Application worker -l info -B
```

Alternatively, you can start both workers as individual services

```
celery -A Application worker -l info

celery -A Application beat -l info
```

Comment: I tried to use -B and it's saying that -B does not work on Windows. How do I run them individually? Different terminals? Can I be in any directory or do I need to be in the app directory? When do I run manage.py runserver before or after starting the workers? Does it have to be in another terminal window?

Comment: 3 terminals / tmux sessions: one for celery worker, one for beat and then one for runserver.

Comment: I opened 3 windows. Navigated to the Application folder on each of them. Ran the worker, beat, and python manage.py runserver and it did not print.

Comment: Might be a problem with timezones or missing configuration. It's pretty tedious debugging without a stacktrace or something else than brief descriptions.